# How to operate Android OS with screen coordinates

Tags: android, operating-system

I have coordinates of screen and I want to tell operating system to perform that operation which OS is supposed to perform on touch of screen on that coordinates.
Just like [cicret](http://cicret.com/wordpress/) somehow tells mobile phone that what to do. While user is not directly interacting with mobile phone.
Plz tell me anything if you know about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.textView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.strXY );
        this.textView.setText("X: ,Y: ");//texto inicial

        this.textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                stringBuilder.setLength(0);

                if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    stringBuilder.append("Moving, X:" + arg1.getX() + ", Y:" + arg1.getY());
                } 
                else {
                    stringBuilder.append("Stoped, X:" + arg1.getX() + ", Y:" + arg1.getY());
                }

                textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```